# Tkinter OptionMenu Error: "bad screen distance" when populating with USB port names

Tags: python, tkinter, pyserial, customtkinter, tkinter.optionmenu

Background: I am a beginner in Python GUI development with Tkinter.
I attempted to populate a Tkinter OptionMenu widget with USB port names retrieved using the serial.tools.list_ports.comports() function. I expected the OptionMenu to display the available USB port names, allowing users to select one. However, I encountered a Tkinter.TclError with the message "bad screen distance" instead.

```
class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.selected_usb_port = ctk.StringVar(self)
        self.usb_ports_with_dev = list_uart_ports()
        if self.usb_ports_with_dev:
            print("USB Ports with '/dev/':", self.usb_ports_with_dev)
            self.selected_usb_port.set(self.usb_ports_with_dev[0])
        else:
            self.selected_usb_port.set("No ports available")
            self.usb_ports_option_menu = ctk.CTkOptionMenu(self.topmenu,  self.selected_usb_port.get(), *self.usb_ports_with_dev, dynamic_resizing=True, pady=10)
            
        self.usb_ports_option_menu.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")
        self.usb_ports_option_menu.place(x=525, y=25)
    def list_uart_ports():
        uart_ports = []
        ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
        for port, desc, hwid in sorted(ports):
            if "USB" in desc:  
                if "ttyUSB" in port or "COM" in port:  
                    uart_ports.append(port)
        return uart_ports
```

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to use [wxpython](https://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started) in that case.

Comment: It is because you pass the arguments to `CTkOptionMenu()` wrong.  Refer to the document.